# How do I subtract Date column given as a character in R?

Tags: r

[image: Store_Entry_Time and Store_Exit_Time are character classes]

I want to add a column which is a subtraction of Store_Entry_Time from Store_Exit_Time.
For example the result for row 1 should be (2014-12-02 18:49:05.402863 - 2014-12-02 16:56:32.394052) = 1 hour 53 minutes approximately.( I want this result in just hours).
I entered class(Store_Entry_Time) and it says "character".
How do I obtain the subtracting and put it into new column as "Time Spent"?

Comment: Add your data using `dput(head(df))` and not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ymd_hms` from `lubridate` to convert the column into `POSIXct` format and then use `difftime` to caluclate the difference in time.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
         mutate(across(c(Store_Entry_Time, Store_Exit_Time), lubridate::ymd_hms),
                Time_Spent = as.numeric(difftime(Store_Exit_Time, 
                               Store_Entry_Time, units = 'hours')))
```

Comment: This works! the data im using has multiple store_id and time spent in it. How do i take average of all time_spent for one store_id?

Comment: After you have ran the above command. Do `df %>%  group_by(Store_Id) %>%
  summarise(aveg_time_spend = mean(time_spent))`

Comment: Will this add a col?

Comment: If you want to add a new column keeping rows as it is, you can use `mutate`. `df <- df %>%  group_by(Store_Id) %>%  mutate(aveg_time_spend = mean(time_spent))`. Don;t forget to assign the data back always `df <- ....`

Comment: That works! How do i get distinct values of store_id vs time_spent? The dataset has multiple store_id rows (with same avg_time_spent) , what i want is one coloumn for each store_id and no duplicates.

Comment: If you check my previous comment with `summarise` it will give you 2 columns, unique store id and time spent. `df1 <- df %>%  group_by(Store_Id) %>%summarise(avg_time_spend = mean(time_spent))`. You can check `df1` after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Im very new to R so sorry for so many questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221995/discussion-between-harshit-chepe-and-ronak-shah).

Answer (score 1):

For a base R option here, we can try using `as.POSIXct`:

```
df$Time_Spent <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(df$Store_Exit_Time) -
                            as.POSIXct(df$Store_Entry_Time)
```

The above column would give the difference in time, measured in hours.

Example:

```
Store_Exit_Time <- "2014-12-02 18:49:05.402863"
Store_Entry_Time <- "2014-12-02 16:56:32.394052"
Time_Spent <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Store_Exit_Time) - as.POSIXct(Store_Entry_Time))
Time_Spent

[1] 1.875836
```

Comment: I tried this but it says "NA" in each value of Time_Spent

Comment: @HarshitChepe Please reload the page, I had some error which is now fixed.

Comment: It says Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: [My answer is working in this demo](https://rextester.com/OGKOK83600).

Comment: Im working on some new data(after some cleaning) and it is in mm//dd//yy , can that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, the call you make to `as.POSIXct` would need to change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222007/discussion-between-harshit-chepe-and-tim-biegeleisen).